# why am i getting html response as data in GET Request of Restful api in android react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cookies

i am trying to fetch data using GET method for an Api.
it returns data in json in ios but in android it return html Script as shown in image,

[image]

```
 let response = await axios.get('https://xxxxxxxx.com/api/reactappsettings/react_get_all_settings/?insecure=cool',
    {headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    },withCredentials:true})
  
     console.log("======>",response);
```

i am stuck here due to this issue, any solutions?

i also tried using react-native-cookie to handle cookies .

```
CookieManager.get('https://mvhardhats.com')
    .then(async (res) => {
      console.log('CookieManager.get =>', res);
       await axios.get(
        `https://mvhardhats.com/api/reactappsettings/react_get_all_settings/?insecure=cool`,
        {
          headers: {
             Cookie:`visid_incap_2485071=${res.visid_incap_2485071}; incap_ses_882_2485071=${res.incap_ses_305_2485071}`,
          },
          withCredentials:true
        },
      ).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
      })
       // => 'user_session=abcdefg; path=/;'
    })
```

but still it returns html even after i got coockies.

Comment: This is because you have been blocked by Incapsula's WAF. There are ways to get around it but if you have access to the Incapsula account the best way is to create a whitelist rule to allow your application to send requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check the whitelist rule in your application and try this code:

**Need to use .json() on the response.**

```
let response = await axios.get('https://mvhardhats.com/api/reactappsettings/react_get_all_settings/?insecure=cool', {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  console.log("======>",response);
});
```

Comment: Gives me this kind of error.    SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (core.js:37)
    at core.js:123
    at JSTimers.js:277
    at _callTimer (JSTimers.js:135)
    at _callImmediatesPass (JSTimers.js:183)
    at Object.callImmediates (JSTimers.js:446)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (MessageQueue.js:396)
    at MessageQueue.js:144
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:373)

Comment: It showing me somekind of error related to cookie. so i made changes using react-native-cookie.

Comment: You're receiving HTML (or XML) back from the server, but the dataType: json is telling jQuery to parse as JSON. Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools to see contents of the server's response. Ask backend developer about the response he is sending to you.